# How to create an automated setup for projects using Eclipse (like Ant)

Tags: java, eclipse, setup-project

It is the following situation:

I currently have multiple Java projects in Eclipse. All the sources, build files etc are checked in at a repository. If a new team member joins the project he has to rebuild the complete setup (setting build path dependencies, adding special libraries).

I thought if that could be automatically done some way, e.g. using an ant file to do all the configurations of eclipse or the servers (tomcat).

Anyone ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the `.classpath` and `.project` files and you should be set!

[(More information about the `.project` file.)](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/project_description_file.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you might use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) too.

But that would require quite an adjustment, I believe.